# Printing Number Image Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, image

```
public class Tester2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] image = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                         {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                         {0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0},
                         {0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0},
                         {0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0},
                         {0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0},
                         {0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0},
                         {0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0},
                         {0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0},
                         {0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0},
                         {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                         {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

        // assume a rectangular image
        int[][] smooth = new int[image.length][image[0].length];

        int sum = 0;
        int col = 0;
        // Compute the smoothed value for non-edge locations in the image.
        for (int row = 1; row < image.length - 1; row++) {
            for (col = 1; col < image[row].length - 1; col++) {
                sum = image[row - 1][col - 1] + image[row - 1][col] + image[row - 1][col + 1] + 
                      image[row][col - 1] + image[row][col] + image[row][col + 1] + 
                      image[row + 1][col - 1] + image[row + 1][col] + image[row + 1][col + 1];
            }
            smooth[row][col] = sum / 9;
        }
        // write out the input
        for (int row = 0; row < image.length; row++) {
            for (int col1 = 0; col1 < image[row].length; col1++) {
                System.out.print(image[row][col1] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < image.length; row++) {
            for (int col1 = 0; col1 < image[row].length; col1++) {
                System.out.print(image[row][col1] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to print the new array. The new array has been created with:

```
sum = image[row-1][col-1] + image[row-1][col] + image[row-1][col+1] + 
       image[row][col-1] + image[row][col] + image[row][col+1] + 
       image[row+1][col-1] + image[row+1][col] + image[row+1][col+1]
```

What can I do to print out the new array?

Comment: Can't you use System.out.print(smooth[row][col1] + " "); to print out the new array?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're printing out the original array twice, and you just need to change the second one to print out the new array instead, changing `image` to `smooth`:

```
for ( int row=0; row < smooth.length; row++ )
{
  for ( int col1=0; col1 < smooth[row].length; col1++ )
    System.out.print( smooth[row][col1] + " ");
  System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the fact that you are printing the image array twice like Hew Wolff suggested, you should also correct your algorithm in order to calculate every pixel of the smooth array:

```
    for (int row = 1; row < image.length - 1; row++) {
        for (col = 1; col < image[row].length - 1; col++) {
            sum = image[row - 1][col - 1] + image[row - 1][col] + image[row - 1][col + 1] + 
                  image[row][col - 1] + image[row][col] + image[row][col + 1] + 
                  image[row + 1][col - 1] + image[row + 1][col] + image[row + 1][col + 1];
            smooth[row][col] = sum / 9;
        }
    }
```